# Regex to preg_replace '\n' and all other escaped characters in a string?

Tags: php, regex

I have a web app which needs to parse string files from iOS apps. I am trying to find all instances of backslash escapes (\n, \t, \, etc) in a string, and add a span class to them, in PHP. For instance,

```
"Hello my name is Jim. \nI have \t12\tdogs"
```

Should become:

```
"Hello my name is Jim.<span class='b'>\n</span> and I have <span class='b'>\t</span>12<span class='b'>\t</span>dogs"
```

Unfortunately my regex skills are beyond rusty. I can't figure out how to not just replace the escapes, but add text on each side while retaining them. How can I do this correctly and efficiently? (will potentially be parsing 1000+ strings at a time)

EDIT: to clarify, I want to replace any possible escape characters, not just t and n. So any 2-character set that begins with a '\', including '\\'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible without regex, which is good for your speed requirement. A simple `str_replace` will work:

```
$string = "Hello my name is Jim. \nI have \t12\tdogs";

$newString = str_replace(
    array("\\t", "\\n"), 
    array("<span class=\"b\">\\t</span>", "<span class=\"b\">\\n</span>"), 
    $string
);
```

Comment: Ended up using this instead of regex, as there is a small number of possibilities to deal with, and the code is way more readable

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP documentation on [Escape Characters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php):

> Single and double quoted PHP strings have special meaning of
>   backslash. Thus if \ has to be matched with a regular expression \\,
>   then "\\\\" or '\\\\' must be used in PHP code.

This is an example with `preg_replace`. Speed isn't an issue for this script.

```
$string = 'Hello my name is Jim. \nI have 1\\\2 of \t12\tdogs\r\n';
$pattern = '!(\\\\t|\\\\n|\\\\r|\\\\v|\\\\e|\\\\f|\\\\$|\\\\"|\\\\\\\\|\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\|\\\\\\\\\\\\)!';
$replacement = "<span class='b'>$1</span>";
$string = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$string);
echo "<pre>$string</pre>";
```

**Output**

```
<pre>Hello my name is Jim. <span class='b'>\n</span>I have 1<span class='b'>\\</span>2 of <span class='b'>\t</span>12<span class='b'>\t</span>dogs<span class='b'>\r</span><span class='b'>\n</span></pre>
```

Comment: I want to do this with any possible escape characters, not just t and n. How could I do that? Basically any time there is a backslash, and then the next character after that. The biggest issue is \\

Comment: That should work there... make it in case there is an escape character. I tried just using your string literally but my server was automatically converting the tabs and newlines.

Comment: There's still something a little off with the \\\ thing. I've gotta get back to work, but this should get you closer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newString = preg_replace('/(\\\\\S)/', '<span class="b">$1</span>', $oldString);
```

One thing to note, when you use `\\` in a PHP string, the resulting string actually contains a single `\`.  `\\\` and `\\\\` will both result in `\\`.

[Example](http://codepad.org/Cuienxaa)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you :

if you wanna match non-printable chars and backslash try this :

```
$newString = preg_replace('/[\s\a\e\\]/', '<span class="b">$1</span>', $oldString);
```

but if you wanna match all printable alpahnum chars that starts with backslash and the "\x**" format try this :

```
$newString = preg_replace('/\\[^[:punct:]\s]|\\\\|\\x[a-fA-F0-9]{1,2}/', '<span class="b">$1</span>', $oldString);
```

this match all chars after backslash expect punctuation chars and chars like \x23, \xAF ...